# React navigation calling the specific function ( From screen C to Screen A)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Screen C:
I have an edit function screen which user allow to delete.

Screen A:
The home page, I have a ready function which is onRefresh function that allows to the page refresh.

From screen C the user delete the function then go to screen A

is that possible to refresh the specific function ?

example.

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
       specific function here
    })
```

My home page code looks like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
   
}

componentWillUnmount = () =>  {

}
componentWillMount() {

    this.getOrderListData(1)
}


onRefresh = () => {

     this.setState({
            onRefreshLoading: true
        }, () => {
            this.getOrderListData(this.state.page)
        })


}
```

Comment: What do you mean refresh the specific function?

Comment: Why not refresh ```screenA``` itself when it's focussed?

Comment: in screen A I have 
    onRefresh() {
        this.setState({
            onRefreshLoading: true
        }, () => {
            this.getOrderListData(this.state.page)
        })

    }

Comment: hmm the problem is home page there's search, filter, and sort, function, each of them have screen type

Comment: @MikeVictoria well, if calling ```onRefresh``` from ```screenC``` solves the problem, then Its better to executed it in focus event.

Comment: Hi @SaachiTech can please give me sample , still confuse . sorry for the noob question.

Comment: @MikeVictoria I posted an answer with sample code.

Comment: @SaachiTech is there a way in react navigation 2 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220900/discussion-between-mike-victoria-and-saachitech).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this case, you want to trigger `onRefresh` in Screen A, when coming back from Screen C.

1. Not sure regarding the function, but you can just pass a param to the Home screen, that Home screen would check on load and refresh if it's specified.

```
  navigation.navigate('Home', {
     refreshOnLoad: true
  })

  ...

  function HomeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
     const { refreshOnLoad } = route.params;
     if (refreshOnLoad) {
        ...
     }
```

2. I would have a common state for the App (Redux or MobX tree), that would be updated in such a case

Comment: sorry i'm confuse, it should be like this ?
class Home extends Component({ route, navigation }) {

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params here is a reference article, it would be this.props.routes

Answer (score 0):

Another way to refresh ScreenA after you navigate it from ScreenC is to add a listener to focus event on navigation, for example in the constructor of ScreenA have a listener like this

```
construction(props){
    ...
    this.focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('focus', this.onRefresh);
    ...
}
```

Dont forget to remove it on `componentWillUnmount()` like this

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.focusListener();
}
```

Hope this helps. You can read more about this [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/).

**React Navigation 2x example**

In react-navigation 2x you have to listen for didFocus event. For example have it like this in your constructor

```
construction(props){
    ...
    this.focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.onRefresh);
    ...
}
```

And then unsubscribe to the event like this

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.focusListener.remove();
}
```

Comment: is there a way in react navigation 2 ?

Comment: @MikeVictoria Updated my answer. I would suggest migrating to 5x as 2x is way older and you won't get much support later on.

Comment: After to migrate you code I having an error in setstate

 this.focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => this.onRefresh); I added event

Comment: How you have onRefresh defined? Is this already bind with the arrow? Also it should be ```this.focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => this.onRefresh())```

Comment: the compoenetwillunmount is will be the same home page ?

Comment: ```compoenetwillunmount ``` will be on the same page where you have the listener defined.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ATAXdVD this is my sample code from home page.

Comment: @MikeVictoria Please post your home page code in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220898/discussion-between-mike-victoria-and-saachitech).

Comment: SaachiTech the code is now working , but I have an filter screen when i go back, dont want to refresh the whole component, the refresh function will be refresh in screen c (delete function screen )

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, Another way to do it.

Screen A:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.onRefresh = this.onRefresh.bind(this);

    }


   onRefresh = () => {

         this.setState({
                onRefreshLoading: true,
                orderList:[]
            }, () => {
                this.getOrderListData(1)
            })


    }


  this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen B', {
                            onRefresh: this.onRefresh,
                        })
```

Screen B passing params to Screen C

```
const { state, setParams, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  const params = state.params || {};

this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen C', {          
  onRefresh: params.onRefresh
 })
```

Screen C :

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenA')
   const { state, setParams, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
   const params = state.params || {};
   this.props.navigation.state.params.onRefresh()
```